# Django with Markdown 2.5.2, html output not behaving as expected

Tags: python, html, django, markdown

I'm working on a web app using Django 1.7.1, and created a markdown filter using the [markdown](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) library.

My markdown filter:

```
from django import template
from markdown import markdown

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='markdown')
def markdown_processor(text):
    return markdown(text)
```

If I pass some string, i.e., "###hey", the browser shows `<h3>hey</h3>` instead of:

#### hey

This is what i have in my html file:

```
{{ my_object.description|markdown }}
```

I've checked `my_object.description` to see if it is a unicode string using:

```
isinstance(my_object.description, unicode)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have found, Django's auto-escape mechanism is what's causing the problem. If you mark the markdown output as safe, Django will not auto-escape it.

```
from django import template
from markdown import markdown
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='markdown')
def markdown_processor(text):
    return mark_safe(markdown(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it, I needed the autoescape template tag.

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ my_object.description|markdown }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, Django's auto-escaping is the culprit. In addition to the other suggests provided, you can mark a filter as "safe" and then the value returned by that filter will not get escaped (notice the use of `is_safe=True`):

```
from django import template
from markdown import markdown

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='markdown', is_safe=True)
def markdown_processor(text):
    return markdown(text)
```